# Syntax highlighting for vimscript in fenced code in StackExchange

Tags: discussion

(Apologies if this question is duplicated. I searched for similar questions but all results that came up were about syntax highlighting within Vim, which is unrelated to my question.)

Is there a way to add syntax highlighting to vimscript in StackExchange fenced code? For example, I can get Python highlighting by opening the fenced code block with *```python*. Is it possible to achieve the same for Vimscript?

I have tried with *```vim* with no luck.

*```vimscript* also didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably they won't ever develop it, saying the little count of the users wanting vimscript help on the SO.

Comment: That is what I suspected. Thank you for confirming it. Sorry for asking here instead of in meta, is there a way to migrate it? Also, do you have any general tips on how to find duplicates? As I explained in the question, Google wasn't helpful here.

Comment: @mgarort No problem for posting here rather than in meta, I already voted to close the question but you can also flag it so that our mods decide if they want to move the question or just close it. About the tips for duplicates excepted using the filter `site:vi.stackexchange.com` on your search engine, there isn't much I can recommend. For this particular question I just remembered it had already been asked that how I knew there was a duplicate but I don't know if I would have found it with a search.